# calendar in java with only for loops

Tags: java, for-loop, calendar

okay so the point is to write a program that produces calendars as output. The program should have
a method monthCalendar(int daysInMonth, int startingDayOfWeek) that outputs a
single month’s calendar like the one below where daysInMonth indicates the number of days in
the month, and startingDayOfWeek indicates the day on which the first of the month falls
(0=Sunday, 1=Monday,…,6=Saturday). You can assume daysInMonth’s range to be [28,31] and
startingDayOfWeek’s range to be [0,6]. 
We cant use if loops , we are restricted to the use of for loops
what i've come up with , really need help to get this right

```
public class Calendar {
public static void main (String[]args){
    monthCalendar(31,6);
  }
public static String padLeft(String s, int totalLength) {
    return String.format("%" + totalLength + "s", s);
                            }
public static String padLeft(int s, int totalLength) {
    return String.format("%" + totalLength + "s", s);
                            }
public static void line(){
    System.out.print("+");
    for(int j=1;j<=7;j++){
        for(int i=1;i<=6;i++){
            System.out.print("-");
                            }
            System.out.print("+");
                            }
            System.out.println();
                            }                                                     
public static void monthCalendar(int daysInMonth , int startingDayOfWeek){
    System.out.print(padLeft("Sun",5));
    System.out.print(padLeft("Mon",7));
    System.out.print(padLeft("Tue",7));
    System.out.print(padLeft("Wed",7));
    System.out.print(padLeft("Thu",7));
    System.out.print(padLeft("Fri",7));
    System.out.print(padLeft("Sat",7));
    System.out.println();
    line();
    System.out.print("|");
    for(int i=1;i<=startingDayOfWeek;i++){
        System.out.print(padLeft("|",7));
  }
    for(int k=startingDayOfWeek;k<7;k++){
            for(int m=1;m<=daysInMonth;m++){
                System.out.print(padLeft(m,4));
                System.out.print(padLeft("|",3));
                int b=1;
                int x=1;
                for(int a=b;a==x*(7-startingDayOfWeek);a++){
System.out.println();
System.out.print("|");
x=x*7;

                                                            }

            }
            }
       line();
            }
          }
```

Help would be really apreciated in solving this exercise , thank you

Comment: Could you find your formatting to make your code more readable?

Comment: what's an `if loop`?

Comment: If you can use for you have if. `if(condition) {}`is equivalent to: `for (int i = 0; (condition && (i < 1)); i++) {}`such block will be executed once when condition is true and won't be executed if condition is false.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i meant an if condition

Comment: @Kacper the professor told us this is not allowed

Comment: I think your `leftpad` helper methods make you code more complicated instead of simpler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey i do agree with you but this is a must use code given by the instructor

Comment: In that case, I would use the IDE to clean up the code so it is readable, and step through it in your debugger until I come to a line which doesn't do what I expect it to.